# mongoose how to skip populating with find document directly when searching ref _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

Schema Lift (models/Lift.js)

```
var LiftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ID: {
  type : String,
  required: true
  }, 
  Name: {
  type : String,
  required: true
  },
  _OEM: {
  type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'OEM'
  },
  _Building: {
  type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Building'
  },
  LastMaintenanceTime: {
  type: Date, 
  default: Date.now 
  },
  StatusCode : {
  type : Number,
  required: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 3
  },
  Status : {
  type : String,
  required: true,
  enum: ['Normal', 'Warnings', 'Maintenance', 'Error'] 
  }}
  );
```

======================================================================
Schema OEM (models/OEM.js)

```
var OEMSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
ID: {
  type : String,
  required: true
 }, 
  Name: {
  type : String,
  required: true
  },
  Address: {
  type : String
  }}
);
```

router/lifts.js

```
var Lift = require('../models/Lift.js');
var OEM = require('../models/OEM.js');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
if(req.query.OEMID){

    if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.query.OEMID) ){
        Lift.
        find({ _OEM: req.query.OEMID }).
        exec(function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
          res.json(result);
        });
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Bad Request : invalid OEMID'});
    }


}
```

The result that I get is null, how do I get the complete result with the correct _id from OEM ?

this line of code seems doesn't work.
**find({ _OEM: req.query.OEMID }).**

With the URL "http://localhost:3000/lifts/OEMID=5971bd7e734d1d6202a81527",
the result I expect as follows ( retrieve 4 lifts from 10 )

```
[
    {
        "_id":"59745b9a734d1d6202a90eb9",
        "ID":"L000001",
        "Name":"Lift AAA",
        "_OEM":{
            "_id":"5971bd7e734d1d6202a81527",
            "ID":"M0001",
            "Name":"Schindler",
            "Address":""
        },
        "_Building":{
            "_id":"5974599d734d1d6202a90e41",
            "ID":"B000001",
            "Name":"Building 1",
            "Address":"3244 Lorem Ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Longitude":"12.12",
            "Latitude":"34.34",
            "StatusCode":0,
            "Status":"Healthy"
        },
        "StatusCode":3,
        "Status":"Error",
        "_LiftError":{ },
        "LastMaintenanceTime":"2011-09-16T11:05:17.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id":"59745bd7734d1d6202a90ec4",
        "ID":"L000002",
        "Name":"Lift BBB",
        "_OEM":{
            "_id":"5971bd7e734d1d6202a81527",
            "ID":"M0001",
            "Name":"Schindler",
            "Address":""
        },
        "_Building":{ },
        "StatusCode":0,
        "Status":"Normal",
        "LastMaintenanceTime":"2011-09-16T11:05:17.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id":"59745da8734d1d6202a90f40",
        "ID":"L000007",
        "Name":"Lift GGG",
        "_OEM":{
            "_id":"5971bd7e734d1d6202a81527",
            "ID":"M0001",
            "Name":"Schindler",
            "Address":""
        },
        "_Building":{ },
        "StatusCode":2,
        "Status":"Maintenance",
        "LastMaintenanceTime":"2011-09-16T11:05:17.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id":"59745e3f734d1d6202a90f59",
        "ID":"L000010",
        "Name":"Lift JJJ",
        "_OEM":{
            "_id":"5971bd7e734d1d6202a81527",
            "ID":"M0001",
            "Name":"Schindler",
            "Address":""
        },
        "_Building":{ },
        "StatusCode":0,
        "Status":"Normal",
        "LastMaintenanceTime":"2011-09-16T11:05:17.000Z"
    }
]
```

But I get this right now

```
[]
```

By the way, the OEM Document I soted in Mongo as below
[image]

and the Lift Document 
[image]

Comment: Show a document you expect to match. If the `ObjectId` being sent is valid and actually matches something then you should get a result. If you get nothing, then it does not match. So show the document as viewed from the `mongo` shell. That will tell us if the stored value is perhaps something else, such as a "string".

Comment: @Neil, I just add the OEM document on my mLab, as you can see.

Comment: I am not asking for the documents in the `OEM` "collection". I am asking about "this collection". Which would be called "lifts" by default. The other collection has nothing to do with "this query".

Comment: @Neil, the Lift Document is added as well, you can see the value stored in  _OEM is an ObjectID.

Comment: It's a "string" and not an `ObjectId`. You can see the clear difference between values that are simply quoted and those wrapped with `$oid`. That is why you get no results. You should actually fix your data since the related field is an `ObjectId` and this field is not.

Comment: Thanks Neil, My problem solved.